# Failed paste into new message (outlook 2007)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Usually on the first try, my paste will fail, and instead I get a tiny multicolored icon. When I magnify it, looks like 2 arrows pointing up and down, contained in a circle. Second try at paste always OK.

Does not matter what I copy, but happens mostly with text or url.

Don't think it's computer related, it has happened on at least 4 different computers running Office 2007.

What does this little icon mean, and why does it take 2 attempts?

Guess this one is going as unresolved.

Comment: Is it possible you could paste a picture of the error icon, and your screen. This would be really helpful in identifying the problem and its solution.

Comment: It said I need a 10 reputation to post an image.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qiCwLz8cS_dGVYMlpQdXRIZDA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See link to pic in previous post

Comment: Wow, didn't expect to stump the experts, Sorry.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't get a chance to get on SU. Been busy for the past few days.

Comment: Was pretty sure I had no 3rd party add-ons except AV, but ran the command anyway. This did not solve the issue. Checked the registry to be sure, and AV was the only 3rd party add-on. But since 2 of the other computers have different AVs, this does not seem to cause it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only thing that seems to be in common on the different machines is Office 2007. Just fired up my old Dell XP desktop, and it also has the issue. Have not had the chance to try it on Win8 with Office 2007, as they seem to come with Office 2010.

Comment: On all of the computers was the same installation media used? Could be that the installation was some how corrupted.

Comment: No, I only used the same installation disk on my  home computers. Bought a laptop with win7 and Office 2007 installed, same problem

Comment: Did you try clicking the icon to see the options? If possible provide a screenshot of thee context menu. It maybe that the data you're trying to paste is causing outlook to flip out the first time. Try pasting that data into notepad and copy it from there

Comment: Outlook seems to identify the icon as a picture with the right click, even with copying from a text file created by notepad

Comment: Please post the data you're trying to paste

Comment: Just another copy of random text, this was created by notepad.

Comment: Just figured this out also. Once copied, I can repeatedly paste OK to other apps.But when I try to paste to outlook, the copied data disappears on first try, and I can no longer paste the data in other apps unless I copy again. Then no more problems until I start Outlook again.

Comment: It appears nobody could solve this problem.I was hoping for a miracle, but problems that stump me usually stump everyone. So I am closing this thread, Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem caused by a third-party add-in. To test this out, simply open a run dialog box and start outlook in safemode. Make sure the Outlook process is not running before starting.

Here are the step by step instructions:

1. Open the Run dialog box.
    For Win 7/Vista/XP, `Start Button (Windows Logo) > Run` 
    For Win 8, `Right-click Start Button (Windows Logo) > Run`
   Or alternatively, Press the `Win + R` shortcut keys
2. Type outlook.exe with the switch safe:3. `outloook.exe /safe:3`

Outlook should open. Try pasting in any data and if the data is pasting in without failure, one of your add-ins is the culprit. You can disable the add-ins one-by-one to find out which one is causing this problem.

Description of what the safe:3 switch does:

> /safe:3   Starts Outlook with Microsoft Exchange Client Extensions (ECE) turned off, but listed in the Add-In Manager. Component Object Model (COM) add-ins are turned off.

Here is the reference to all of the Outlook 2007 command-line switches: [Command-line switches for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-outlook-2007-HP001218589.aspx)

If the problem still persists, reply back and let me know.